# What is the real depth of the Mojave crater on Mars?

Tags: mars, geology, crater, topography

[image: Mojave crater]

The [Mojave crater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojave_(crater)) on Mars is interesting because among other things, it has [alluvial fans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alluvial_fan) that look remarkably similar to landforms in the [Mojave desert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojave_Desert).

On the image<sup>1</sup> above the crater has about the same color like the northwestern floor of [Gale crater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gale_(crater)), being about **4,400 meters** below Martian "sea level".
But the [description on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojave_(crater)#Description) says the depth of Mojave is approximately **2,600 meters.**

So, what is the real depth of Mojave crater?

<sup>1</sup>*Image from [USGS MC-11](https://planetarynames.wr.usgs.gov/images/mc11_mola.pdf). An [alternative map](https://astropedia.astrogeology.usgs.gov/download/Mars/Nomenclature/thumbnails/mc11_2014-full.jpg).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NASA confirms](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/MRO/multimedia/pia12840.html) the latter - **2600m**:

> The depth of the crater -- about 2.6 kilometers (1.6 miles) -- also demonstrates that Mojave has experienced little infilling or erosion.

The terrain was mapped using stereo pairs of images from the [HiRISE imager](https://hirise.lpl.arizona.edu/) on the Mars Reconnaissance Orbiter.

I believe the confusion is from comparing depth vs elevation. Mojave Crater is in the outflow region of [Valles Marineris](https://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/imagegallery/image_feature_83.html) into [Chryse Planitia](https://mars.nasa.gov/resources/6092/chryse-planitia-surfaces/), an area that is already ~2km below zero-elevation. So although Mojave Crater is 2.6km deeper than its surroundings, it's ~4.5km below 'sea-level'.

Comment: Thank you, i think you've expained the confusion, although i dont think Mojave Crater is on **the edge** of Chryse Planitia. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2a/Chryse_Planitia_Map_Relative.png

Comment: If i compare the colors of Mojave crater and its  surroundings on the MOLA map, then the surroundings are already at minus 4 km. unless the rim of the crater is supposed to be the surrounding.

Comment: @Conelisinspace yes, I believe the definition of 'depth' being used by NASA here is roughly 'difference in elevation from the lowest point to the rim'

Answer (score 1):

Like the answer from @Jack already noted, the confusion is indeed from comparing depth vs elevation.
What i really wanted to know was the depth below "sea level".
With [Mars Trek's](https://trek.nasa.gov/mars/) "Calculate Elevation Profile" tool you can find that the floor of Mojave crater is about **5.1 km** below "sea level", 600 meters lower than Gale crater's !
Together with [Nicholson crater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholson_(Martian_crater)) it is one of the deepest craters near the equator of Mars.